# How many flying hours does one need to become a commercial pilot in the Philippines?

Tags: pilots, philippines

I'm trying to calculate all the expenses to become a pilot in the Philippines.

Comment: It's a good idea to narrow your question to one jurisdiction (EU/ US etc.) :)

Comment: and on a second note, it's also good to write what type of pilot you're trying to become: commercial or private?

Comment: Saw that you edited it to include 'commercial', but it's great if you can add which area/ country of the world you are in- otherwise this is very broad....

Comment: ...and are you considering being a fixed wing aircraft pilot or a helicopter pilot?

Answer (score 1):

While CAAP seems to be pretty (or even very) vague on the topic, this is what I've been able to find:

**To start with the private pilots license:**

> You must also complete the required minimum of 40 hours of widespread flight training. The hours of flight time consists of at least 20 hours of dual flight instruction, at least 10 hours of solo flight, and 10 hours of which can be solo flights or dual.

**Then you will need to build on this to get a commercial pilots license:**

> You will need about 220 hours of total flight time to get your CPL.

* Another source suggests you need a minimum of 150 hours. Be aware however that this is not an exact science: Even for the PPL it can take 60 hours to 'get the feeling for it', so it is difficult to estimate exactly how much you will need. While I'm not a pilot myself I think it's a good idea to be on the conservative side and overestimate the hours you will need for a PPL and CPL.

[Source](http://www.wccaviation.com/index.php/blog/155-quick-guide-in-getting-your-pilot-licenses-in-the-philippines)

This is probably unfortunately what you have also been able to find. It is however a very good idea to go past the flight school in person and talk to them about this topic, since it's uncommon, and they can probably give you a better estimate. Be aware that there can be several more costs that are not visible at first sight (checkrides for instance) that can add to the tally so even the ones that appear the cheapest are not.